Trying to figure out a way to use some algebra in excel for a very specific purpose
So, I'm trying to build out a budget. I have some variables:
The DEBT which is calculated by my current debt (a fixed number) plus the sum of what I'm intending to spend each day for the next year, lets call that SPEND.
My INCOME for the year in question which is fixed, but is variable based on if I have some windfall that arises
and my DAILY BUDGET, which I've currently calculated manually by using the fixed numbers for debt and income and dividing by 365. What I would like to do, is have my daily budget ADJUST if I go over or under budget on a day, so lets say if my budget is 60 dollars on a given day and I spend 400 dollars—I'd then like the daily budget number for the rest of the year to populate out to the slightly smaller number—or conversely if I underspend I'd like the budget to go up to the slightly larger number. I can't figure out the equation for this. It will need to be some kind of solve for X scenario where it all adds up to zero:
(INCOME-(CURRENT DEBT)-SPEND)-(DAILY BUDGET)*365=0 where INCOME and DEBT are fixed, and SPEND is a variable that depends on the average amount I plan to spend each day for the year. I'm wondering if this is a multivariable solution that will involve me calculating the max value that the budget can be while satisfying the equation, but I'm lost on how to do that. There's also definitely a bit of circular logic happening since the SPEND and DAILY BUDGET variables depend on each other a bit. Let me know if anyone can help, I hope this makes sense.


The sophisticated algebra here is to calculate the budget based on the remaining debt and the remaining number of days:
[B4] =B1
[D4] and fill down =B4/(DATE(2026,1,1)-A4)
[B5] and fill down =B4-IF(ISBLANK(C4);D4;C4)

Actual Spent should be manually entered at the end of each wonderful day. Enter 0 if no spent.
